# What does the function $E$ stand for in WolframAlpha's solution to this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

While trying to find the circumference of an ellipse, I came up with this result in Wolfram Alpha.

Equation: $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} =1$

[image]

While trying to perform the definite integral, the computation timed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha usually specifies things like these below the equation and to the right, often linking to properties and definitions. [Indeed, putting your integral into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20sqrt(1%20%2B%20(b%5E4%20x%5E2)%2F(a%5E2(a%5E2%20b%5E2%20-%20b%5E2%20x%5E2)))%20dx):

[image]

The function $E$, here, refers to elliptic integrals of the second kind.

The site also links to its [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) and a [page on its properties and such](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/).

Sadly, all this is way above my head, so in parsing said information I will likely be of absolutely no help to you. Good luck though!

Comment: Sorry. I was using the mobile version of the site. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately I think even I won't be able to understand this.

Comment: It's not unsurprising that the arc length of an ellipse is expressed in terms of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).  That's what elliptic integrals were originally invented for.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It was surprising for me because I thought that I will be able to get a formula for the circumference of an ellipse.

Comment: I mean, you have one. Just an unbelievably complicated one. :P